# How to zip lists of uneven length

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I have 3 lists.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> c = ['x','y','z']
```

I wish to zip them in a manner that no element is left out. Does such a function exist in python which can perform the following task?

```
>>> myzip(a,b,c)
[(1, 'a','x'), (2, 'b','y'), (3, 'c','z'), (4,'d'), (5)]
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: ``list(izip_longest(a, b,c))``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) and list comprehension like this

```
from itertools import izip_longest
print [tuple(j for j in i if j is not None)for i in izip_longest(a, b, c)]
# [(1, 'a', 'x'), (2, 'b', 'y'), (3, 'c', 'z'), (4, 'd'), (5,)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
b=[1,2]
c=[1]

print map(None,a,b,c)


#output [(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, None), (3, None, None), (4, None, None)]

print [tuple(j for j in i if j)for i in map(None,a,b,c)]
#output [(1, 1, 1), (2, 2), (3,), (4,)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import izip_longest

a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = ['a','b','c','d']
c = ['x','y','z']
print list(izip_longest(a,b,c))
[(1, 'a', 'x'), (2, 'b', 'y'), (3, 'c', 'z'), (4, 'd', None), (5, None, None)]
```

You can also specify a different  `fillvalue`, `None` is the default:

```
print list(izip_longest(a, b, c,fillvalue=0))
[(1, 'a', 'x'), (2, 'b', 'y'), (3, 'c', 'z'), (4, 'd', 0), (5, 0, 0)]
```